# ¿ Alguien sabría actualizar desde el CMD o PowerShell, las actualizaciones que aparecen en Windows Update?

Tags: windows, shell

No se si es posible realizar esto, debido a que quiero realizar un script en Windows 10, que actualice directamente, sin necesidad de utilizar Windows Update

Comment: Busca sobre PSWindowsUpdate y WindowsUpdateProvider, es lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Powershell

Ejecuta powershell como administrador y ejecuta estos 2 comandos:

1. `Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate`: Instala los paquetes de comandos necesarios
2. `Install-WindowsUpdate`: Instala las actualizaciones pendientes

También puedes usar `Get-WindowsUpdate` para listar las actualizaciones pendientes antes de instalarlas.

---

### CMD

Por lo que he leído, ya no hay forma de actualizar desde el CMD. Lo comandos eran `wuauclt` o `UsoClient`, pero ambos están obsoletos en Windows 10.